# library(rgl) breaks R on Windows

Tags: r, rgl

Loading the `rgl` library causes R Console and RStudio to break.

I get a Windows error message:

> R for Windows GUI front-end has stopped working

or

> RStudio R Session has stopped working.

I'm using R version 3.5.3 64 bit and the latest *rgl* version 0.100.19. The problem appeared after updating some packages this week.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your video driver, but it is hard to diagnose without seeing it.

Comment: While the problem appears to be solved, it is worth trying running the package in "raw" mode, e.g. running Rgui.exe. Unless "R console" refers to rgui.exe, then ignore my comment. :)

Comment: you need top install the `rgl` package from sources, with a help of devtools package

Answer (score 1):

It was probably a video driver issue. Windows Update solved the problem.